# How to fix less error while compiling bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

Attached is a trace while compiling using `grunt dist`

```
(webmaker)Anils-MacBook-Pro:bootstrap anil$ grunt dist
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task

Running "less:compileCore" (less) task
>> ArgumentError: error evaluating function `ceil`: argument must be a number in less/variables.less on line 48, column 27:
>> 47 @font-size-base:          15px;
>> 48 @font-size-large:         ceil(@font-size-base * 1.25); // ~18px
>> 49 @font-size-small:         ceil(@font-size-base * 0.85); // ~12px
Warning: Error compiling less/bootstrap.less Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The `grunt-contrib-less` is the latest version and as can be seen, the variable @font-size-base is defined just above and it works.

A similar thread I found https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/brackets-dev/ZpBOFqDc3H8 but no solutions yet.

Comment: It looks like it's compiled with `--strict-math=on` Less option but Boosrtrap 3.0.3 (and below) requires `--strict-math=off`. (Contrary the current Boosrtrap master requires `--strict-math=on`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is probably to add extra parentheses to the `@font-size-large` and `@font-size-small` lines.

Before:

```
@font-size-large:         ceil(@font-size-base * 1.25); // ~18px
@font-size-small:         ceil(@font-size-base * 0.85); // ~12px
```

After:

```
@font-size-large:         ceil((@font-size-base * 1.25)); // ~18px
@font-size-small:         ceil((@font-size-base * 0.85)); // ~12px
```

I'm guessing this has happened because you, like me, changed `@font-size-base`, and a bad merge for some reason protected that line, but also the following two lines. (Something changed between 3.0 and 3.1 that means those lines need double parentheses--see `@font-size-h1`, `@font-size-h2`, etc.)